# Unity: event for level reload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using [OnLevelWasLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html) but this event is getting fired on any level load, be it the same level reload or next level load. Is there any event which gets fired only when the level is reloaded, and not fired when the level is loaded?

If not, how can I achieve this in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the new buildindex is the same as the last scene buildindex. OnLevelWasLoaded already gives you the build index of the new scene loaded. You can save lastlevel in a static variable in some class and access it from there. For example "MyClass":

```
void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level){
    if (level != MyClass.lastlevel) return;
    MyClass.lastlevel = level;
    //your other code
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. But got stuck somewhere else, and forgot all about it. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: I was using the same approach but the problem was that I was using `DontDestroyOnLoad` in the same script, because of which `OnLevelWasLoaded` was getting called twice and messing everything up.

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad has its uses but I generally avoid it :p